# How to select this element in Javascript? - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web-scraping

I'm new to javascript and I've been trying for an hour to select this from a web app:

```html
<button type="button" class="zp-button zp_zUY3r zp_B5hnZ zp_rhXT_ zp_FVbJk finder-select-multiple-entities-button" fdprocessedid="jowqnd"><div class="zp_kxUTD" data-elem="button-label"><div class="zp_fwjCX" data-input="checkbox" data-cy-status="unchecked"></div></div><i class="zp-icon apollo-icon apollo-icon-caret-down-small zp_dZ0gM zp_j49HX zp_sGyhf"></i></button>
```

I've been trying to select it by the **"zp_FVbJk"** class.

```js
const dropdownSelector = 'zp_FVbJk'
// Handles button and has to be the same in popup.js and content.js until I find a better solution
function sharedTempHandleButton() {
    console.log("sharedTempHandleButton() started.");

    let buttonToClick;

    buttonToClick = document.getElementsByClassName(dropdownSelector)[0];

    console.log(buttonToClick)

    if (buttonToClick) {
        console.log("Button found: ", buttonToClick);
        buttonToClick.click();
    } else {
        console.error('Button not found using the provided CSS selector');
    }
}
```

It returns buttonToClick as undefined.

I've tried:

- Changing selector to '.zp_FVbJk'
- Using queryselector()

Comment: When does your code run? Elements can only be found if they're actually in the DOM when you look for them.

Comment: When I click a button, I wait for the page to load. Could there be an issue with that?

Comment: Yes, it logs to the console as you can see in the code.

Comment: Right, but it logs either `undefined` or a DOM element. If the element is in the DOM, then `.getElementsByClassName()` or `.querySelector()` will find it. If not, then it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `getElementsByClassName` to select the button by its class name. If that's not working, there might be a few reasons.

So, I suggest you use `querySelector` and hope my code using `querySelector``` might be helpful.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let buttonToClick = document.querySelector('.zp_FVbJk');

    if (buttonToClick) {
        console.log("Button found: ", buttonToClick);
        buttonToClick.click();
    } else {
        console.error('Button not found using the provided CSS selector');
    }
});
```

Comment: When I tried querySelector before, I didn't put the punctuation before the class name (i.e I used "zp_FVbJk" instead of ".zp_FVbJk" 

Comment: I'm glad to see you happy.

Comment: Why would the different API help? If there's an element with that class in the DOM, then *either* function will find it.

Comment: Unticked by accident